# How to nest inline template components?

Tags: vue.js

I have an `<overview>` component, holding all of my contacts in a prop.

Within the overview, I iterate through the contacts and display table rows accordingly.

However, within every table row, I would like to use a dedicated `<contact>` component for specific methods.

I want to use this nested functionality because I'm using the same `<overview>` component for different data listings. And within each table row, I would then use either a `<contact>` or `<project>` component for example.
That way, I could organize specific component methods and such.

But I can't seem to find a way to make this work.

https://jsfiddle.net/vbu8x8ko/

**Edit**: Would I be better off creating different overview components,
such as `<overview-contacts>`, and then use mixins for any shared overview functionality?

If I do that, I wouldn't have a nested component for every table row.

Although I would still like to know how to get nested inline templates to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The value of `contact` created by 'v-for' attribute in component `<overview>` can't pass into the component `<contact>`,I think that data-passing might need be property of component, rather than temporary variable in `inline-template` mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may have happened in the `inline-template` mode. Although it allows more flexible template-authoring, `inline-template` makes scope of your templates harder to reason about.
I suggest that you could put inner content of overview and contact components into their template by template string instead of `inline-template`,as follow:

```js
Vue.config.debug = true;
Vue.config.devtools = true;
Vue.component('overview', {
   props: [ 'contacts', 'columns' ],
    template: `<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <template v-for="column in columns">
                        <th>{{ column }}</th>
                    </template>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="value in contacts">
                    <contact :contact="value" :columns="columns"></contact>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>`
});


Vue.component('contact', {
    props: [ 'contact', 'columns' ],
  template: `<div><td v-for="column in columns">{{ valueForColumn(column) }}</td></div>`,
    methods: {

        valueForColumn(column)
        {
        debugger
            if (column == 'name')
            {
               return this.contact.firstName +' '+ this.contact.lastName;
            }
        }
    }
});


new Vue({
   el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <overview :contacts="[
        {
          'id':1,
          'firstName':'John',
          'lastName':'Doe'
        },
        {
          'id':2,
          'firstName':'John',
          'lastName':'Doe'
        },
        {
          'id':3,
          'firstName':'John',
          'lastName':'Doe'
        }
    ]"
    :columns="[ 'id', 'name' ]"
    ></overview>
</div>
```